# Amd, requirejs - want to ensure something always executes last

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application

I'm trying to avoid global scope for the following problem, but cannot see a way to avoid it.

I have a singleton Javascript object called "Application". This is an AMD module.

I then have many "Modules" (not to be confused with AMD modules) which are just javascript objects that I'd like to register with the "Application" instance.

For example:

```
 require(['Application'], function(app) {

        var module = {
            name: "theme-switcher",
            start: function() { console.log("started") } }

        app.registerModule(module)
 }
```

The architecture I am going for, is i'd like for each "Module" on the page to register itself with the "Application" instance.

Here is the tricky part: Only once ALL modules have been registered with the application, do I then want the "Application" instance, to loop through those registered modules and call their "Start()" methods.

The way I thought to do this was to just add another require block at the bottom of the page like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
require(['Application'], function (app) {
    // start all the registered modules running.
    app.start(() => {
        // this could be a call back function once all modules started..
    });
});
```

Niavely thinking, that just because this require call was last, that it would allways be executed last. But actually, sometimes this gets fired BEFORE the require calls above - so the Application attempts to Start() all registered modules BEFORE the modules themselves have all registered themselves with the Application.

No matter how I think about this problem, I am often led back to the fact that I need to keep some state in global scope, Something like this:

Module 1:

```
var app = Application.Instance;
var moduleStart = function(){
    require(['jquery'], function(jquery) {

 // do module goodness here.
}};

app.registerModule({name: "theme-switcher", start: moduleStart })
```

// later on in page - some other widget
// Module 2

```
var app = Application.Instance;
var moduleStart = function(){
    require(['jquery'], function(jquery) {

 // do second module goodness here.
}};

app.registerModule({name: "foo", start: moduleStart })


And then at the bottom of the page,
var app = Application.Instance;
app.Start(); // loops through registered modules calling start() method.
```

Surely there must be a way to do this avoiding global scope?

The reason for me wanting to do this, is that I want the "Application" to manage the lifecycle for registered modules on the page - including starting / pausing / stopping them etc. I'd also like the Application to publish an event once ALL modules gave been started - as this is when I would typically stop displaying my "loading" animation, and actually display the DOM - as modules will often manipulate the DOM in their start() methods and I don't want the page to be visible before everything is started.

Comment: Why don't you want your "modules" to be RequireJS AMD modules? I'm confused by this.

Comment: If my modules were defined as requireJS AMD modules, i'd still have to require() them, and register them with the Application instance - so how does that help me solve my problem? Even if they took "Application" as a dependency, how could I ensure that all of my Modules have registered themselves with the application before I call "Application.Start()"

Comment: I have also thought about inverting dependencies, i.e so Application AMD module could "depend" upon all of my Modules. However, I want to avoid this, as this would be a different list per page, and constantly changing. Also  I want to allow modules to be dynamically added / removed from the page, so really i need to allow the module to be registered / unregistered with the application instance, rather than have any kind of hardcoded dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it. If you make every object you are wanting an **AMD module**, which I think you should be doing if you have RequireJS in place anyway, then you'll just need an array of strings defining those AMD module names to pass as an argument to the app's init.

**Application.js : -**

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var modules = {};
    var moduleNames = [];
    var numberOfModules = 0;
    var loadedModules = 0;

    exports.init = function (dependencies) {
        numberOfModules = dependencies.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfModules; i++){
            var name = dependencies[i];
            moduleNames.push(name);

            require([name], function (moduleRef) {
                loadedModules++;
                modules[name] = moduleRef;

                if (numberOfModules === loadedModules) {
                    exports.start();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    exports.start = function () {
        // all modules available
        // use modules.myModuleName to access the module.
        modules.myModuleName.functionName();

        // or if they all have start() function and it needs calling

        for (var i = 0; i < moduleNames.length; i++) {
            modules[moduleNames[i]].start();
        }
    };

});
```

**USAGE** Depending on how you are loading your app, assuming you have an Application reference somewhere, just call:

```
// names of modules RequireJS uses to require, can be changed for each page.
var dependencies = ['moduleOne', 'moduleTwo', 'myModuleName'];
app.init(dependencies);
```

CodePen of this code, slightly altered to work on one page... http://codepen.io/owenayres/pen/MyMJYa

Comment: Thanks, this is the idea of inverting the dependencies, so rather than Module --> Application, the Application --> All Modules. I think this might be the right direction to go in, but the problem I have with it is that I want developers to be able develop and add new modules to the page, and have some API available so they can include / register their module in the application dependencies list. I'll explore this a little more, perhaps I can use shim Dependencies for this? Or I need the dependencies list to be in global scope so that they can add their modules to it..

Comment: @Darrell you could convert the above into an API. Just make a new module called moduleService.js or something and make use of this for registering modules and attaching them to the object/arrays used in my example.

Comment: The code shown in this answer won't work. Besides the banal issue that `mymodule` is not initialized anywhere, calling `require` like shown in the code here will result in a failure. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21786807/1906307) for the technical details.

Comment: @Louis Thanks for pointing out `mymodule`, this was a typo when pasting into SO. This code is tested and does as intended... I have multiple implementations similar to this having worked with Require for some time.

Comment: @OwenAyres You did not test it correctly. See the answer I pointed to. (And I'd say that that bug with `mymodule` is prima facie evidence that the code you show in the answer was not in fact what you tested.)

Comment: @Louis I know of this issue, I've encountered it before. The code will call the `start` function of the module successfully. The `mymodule` typo is because I renamed `mymodule` to `name`, but forgot to update the other two references

Comment: @Louis I implore you to test this yourself... I've just re-added it into a RequireJS application and it worked. I appreciate your efforts to help though. I'll get an example posted if I get time.

Comment: For RequireJS to perform the transformation necessary for the CommonJS sugar, which is what you are using, the `require` call must be done with a string literal. It cannot be a variable. `require("foo")` is fine. `var foo = "foo"; require(foo);` is not fine. If you *happen* to have already loaded the modules somewhere else, the `require` calls won't fail, but that's by luck, not by design. That's the path towards intermittent loading issues rather than a stable code base.

Comment: @OwenAyres - I don't think making an AMD module to manage this dependencies list is an option that would work. It would change the dependency structure to this Module --> ModuleService, Application --> ModuleService. The application could then load before all the modules were registered. So this leads back to the same problem - I need to be some state in global scope and in this case its the dependencies list, as well as an API to manipulate it :(

Comment: Also apologies if I am using the term "global scope" incorrectly - I basically mean I always need to end up putting some JS code "outside" of an AMD module, that executes immediately as the page is rendered (not aynchornously) so that I can guarantee order of execution and and maintain some state somewhere that is setup prior to my require() calls. In this case its an API to manipulate a "dependencies" list, that I would then use later within the application.init().

Comment: @Louis Upvoted that, thank you Louis... Sorry, only had half my attention on that and it was of course because the example I chucked it in was because the module was already loaded. Tweaked the answer so it *does* work now... wrapped it in the callback.

Comment: @Darrell what's wrong with manipulating the dependencies list? The modules will load and `start()` in the order they're defined in that list. The API could dynamically register new modules *after* all the others have loaded in, which I thought is what you meant?

Comment: @OwenAyres - Close, I need the "modules" / dependencies list to be entirely dynamic - i.e it needs to reflect the components that are actually on the page, and these components can be added and removed from the page - which means they need to register themselves as dependencies for this model to work. Thats fine, but again - in order to register themselves as dependencies - I think that has to be done outside of an AMD module - within global scope, so that all registration is forced to occur before any require() calls.

Comment: I think i'm going to accept this answer, and also accept the fact that not everything can be done inside AMD modules. For this answer to work, i'm pretty certain I will have to have modules "register" themsevles into a master list that is held in global scope (not within an AMD module). This registration would occur before Application.Init to ensure that the list is fully populated.

Comment: @Darrell how do you identify the required components? Take a second look at my CodePen (http://codepen.io/owenayres/pen/MyMJYa). I have modified it to now enter an AMD module that will identify required components, form an array of dependencies and then attach those dependencies to `app`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112422/discussion-between-darrell-and-owen-ayres).

Comment: We came to the conclusion that as for my use case, I want the list of modules for a page to be configurable, that it makes sense to store this infromation (list of modules on the page) in the backend database, and then on page load, grab this list from the db. Marking as asnwer

Comment: The only thing I'd do differently from what is in the code here is perform a single `require` with the list of module names, and then in the callback use `arguments` to match names to module objects. RequireJS can optimize the module loading better if it gets the list in one call than in a series of calls.